# VB.NET parsing and processing a file containing several different record types

Tags: vb.net, parsing

Which design pattern/model would be most suited to this scenario:

I am parsing a data file that contains 7 different types of records. The fields contained in these records are to be used to generate 6 different CSV files. Each file could be composed of one or more of the fields from the records.

I am writing this in VB.NET.

I am trying to avoid (if possible) the following:

```
Select Case
  Case RecordType = 1 Then
   'Populate file A
  Case Record Type = 2 Then
   'Populate file B
  Case RecordType = 3 Then
   'Populate file A + B 
  etc...
Case
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which record type maps to which file?

Comment: The first field in each record has an identifier which indicates what type of record it is. Each report will comprise of one or more record types. Eg. record type 1 relates to cars. I therefore know its contents will be included in the Vehicle Report.

Comment: Given what you describe, the CASE statement is exactly how I would attack this problem.  It's an easy way to separate the data while only making one pass through the file.  Is there a specific reason you don't want to use the CASE statement you included?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a "correct" OO method of accomplishing the above taking into account that my CASE statement will very quickly start to become cluttered as certain reports will need multiple record lines.

Comment: Personally I would Case records out to 7 tables, and then generate CSV's pulling from whatever tables were applicable. That keeps things organized, and relatively easy to update.